# What's the difference between »das Einkaufen« and »der Einkauf«?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between

1. der Einkauf
2. das Einkaufen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the answer by PiedPiper (which mentions the differences in meaning; you'll find more such differences if you read through the
two respective entries at dwds.com) there's also a difference in the way these nouns are built:

*Der Einkauf* is a noun with the stem *kauf*. *Kauf* has existed as a derivation since the ninth century. (Cf. the Etymologisches Wörterbuch by Wolfgang Pfeifer, as quoted at https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kauf).

On the contrary, *das Einkaufen* is a verb turned into a noun (a *Substantivierung*) according to modern grammar rules. 
You won't even find it in most dictionaries, as this type of noun is not considered »self-contained« (I don't know how to put it more correctly). 
You'll have to read the definition of the verb *einkaufen* to get the meaning of the noun.

Comment: Der Einkauf ist auch eine Sektion des Unternehmens (Einkauf, Marketing, Personal, ...).

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt. Ich belasse die Antwort jetzt einfach mal, wie sie ist, da ich keine Sammlung von Bedeutungen beginnen wollte. Das passt vielleicht besser in die Antwort von PiedPiper.

Answer (score 4):

These can both be translated as 'shopping', but there are differences:

**Das Einkaufen** is shopping in the sense of 'going shopping'

**Der Einkauf** is a purchase, or shopping in the sense of 'what was bought'